# How to disable Gmail Api guava 20

Tags: gradle, gmail, gmail-api, guava

I implemented Gmail API to get some confirmation tokens from email. With Gmail Api automatically when you run the "Gradle run" command from git come to this guava dependency guava 20, but that dependency causing me some issues so I have to add guava 25.

Now I would like to disable the old guava dependency > but I don't know-how. I have tried all known solutions from Stackoverflow but nothing helped me. In the end, I removed that dependency directly from the folder but now, my code doesn't compile, so I don't know what to do.

[image: Image1]
GMail API

```
package GmailAPIPackage;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListMessagesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GmailQuickstart {

private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";

private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

/**
* Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
* If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
*/

private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_MODIFY);

private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

/**
* Creates an authorized Credential object.
* @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
* @return An authorized Credential object.
* @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
*/

private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {

// Load client secrets.

InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);

if (in == null) {
throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
}

GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.

GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
.setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))

.setAccessType("offline")
.build();

LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}

public static void getToken() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

// Build a new authorized API client service.

final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
.setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)

.build();

// Print the labels in the user's account.

String user = "me";

ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();

if (labels.isEmpty()) {

System.out.println("No labels found.");

} else {

System.out.println("Labels:");

for (Label label: labels) {

System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());

}
}

// Access Gmail inbox

Gmail.Users.Messages.List request = service.users().messages().list(user).setQ("from: " + "notification@casinosieger.com");

ListMessagesResponse messagesResponse = request.execute();

request.setPageToken(messagesResponse.getNextPageToken());

        // Get ID of the email you are looking for
        String messageId = messagesResponse.getMessages().get(0).getId();

        Message message = service.users().messages().get(user, messageId).execute();
        
        

        // Print email body

        String emailBody = StringUtils
                .newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(message.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getParts().get(1).getBody().getData()));

        System.out.println("Email body : " + emailBody);   
}
}
```

RegFirstCase MainClass

```
package GmailAPIPackage;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import com.google.api.client.repackaged.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListMessagesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;

public class RegFirstCase extends GmailQuickstart{
    
public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Selenium\\selenium-java-3.141.59\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https:\\www.casinosieger.com\\en\\register");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

int i = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100000, 1000000);

driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("Stefan" + i);
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("stefan.t+" +i+ "@condor-gaming.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("Gordana1994");

Actions act =  new Actions(driver);
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("terms"))).click().perform();

driver.findElement(By.id("is_of_legal_age")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("register")).click();

Thread.sleep(5000);

GmailQuickstart.getToken();
System.out.println("Stigao dovde");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(https)://([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([[\\w+,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?(token)(\\=)([^\"]+)");  
Matcher m = p.matcher("token=(.*)");  
boolean b = m.matches();  
System.out.println(b);


}
}
```

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'GmailQuickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.24.1'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.24.1'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev95-1.24.1'
}
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:20.0' , module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

Error message when guava 20 hasn't been removed from the folder directly:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at GmailAPIPackage.RegFirstCase.main(RegFirstCase.java:33)
```

Error message after gradle dependencies has been run:

```
C:\Users\Stefan.T\Desktop\GmailApi>gradle dependencies
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Stefan.T\Desktop\GmailApi\build.gradle' line: 14

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GmailApi'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 27s

C:\Users\Stefan.T\Desktop\GmailApi>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you show the output of of `gradle dependencies`? [`guava-api-client-1.24.1` shouldn't include guava-jdk5 anymore](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues/903), so the exclude is probably noop and just overwriting Guava version to 25.0 should be enough.

Comment: Write your configuration here. Don't put screenshots, I want to test things out myself to help you and I can't copy/paste from your screenshot, and I definitely won't retype everything, especially since all things being equal, you might have a typo issue.

Comment: I apologize, Olivier, I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi Xaerxess, I have added the output to the question.

Comment: Please run command `gradle dependencies` and provide an output here

Comment: I have updated my question with this output. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for this, I have created a new Gradle project from scratch(not by Gmail instructions from here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#prerequisites
and now everything works as expected. I just want to add that I don't understand why Gmail is not updated their instructions (they are using a lot of not up to date things) and because of it we're losing our nerves :D